# is it wise to use 3 ports for a server application?

Tags: c#, sockets, client-server, port

I have a server-client application [TCP sockets, .NET 4.0]..
the application about :

do the commands that received from the client

receives files

send a screenshot image
the application should do the 3 tasks in the same time

After i done that and it worked .. i realized that these kind of application should use one port for all tasks .. like Radmin and netsupport .. etc 
but i used 3 ports .. one to keep receiving commands any time the client sends. and one for receiving files .. and one if the client asked for a screenshot

so is it fine to use 3 ports for a network application? ..

I've tried to create 3 sockets on the client side to connect to server on the same port (ex:9090)
but when i tried to send a file from the client .. the server received the bytes in Job function that's should receives the commands only... so it looks like i can't use one port for those tasks
 so is it possible use one port for all of the three tasks that they may work at the same time?

```
    private void ClientAccept()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Socket client = server.Accept();
            Console.WriteLine(client.RemoteEndPoint + " has connected");
            NetworkStream stream = new NetworkStream(client);
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            string line = reader.ReadLine();
            if (line == "1")           //it means its a command socket
            {
                thJob = new Thread(Job);
                thJob.Start(cmdClient);
            }
            else if(line=="2")        //its a data socket
            {
                FileTransfer ft = new FileTransfer(client);
            }
         }
      }

    private void Job(object o)
    {
        Socket s = (Socket)o;
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(new NetworkStream(s));
        string cmd = null;
        while ((cmd = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            //bla bla
        }
    }
```

**Added question:**
lets say the server has one port.
the client connect to server for commands .. let's call it cmdClient which its port is 11589
then a Job Thread started for this client like the code up.
then the client connect with another socket to the server .. dataClient which its port is 1800 
 then when i use the dataClient to send a file .. the server receives the bytes at the job Method .. !! why does that happene?

Comment: The server listens only on a single port, but the client opens multiple TCP connections?

Comment: @CodeInChaos yupp! then how should it be done?

Comment: Your question title sounded like you listen on three different ports on the server, which would have been strange. But just having a few connections isn't unusual.

Comment: One could use a protocol that supports multiplexing, but that would add considerable complexity.

Comment: i think you are right .. im gonna stay on my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is wise to use multiple ports when doing file transfers. It would require a quite advanced protocol to use the same port and still keep the application response (as you still have to be able to send commands during file transfers).

But I do not recommend you to use three fixed ports. Use one port for all commands and an arbitrary number of ports for the file transfers.

A file transfer would look like this:

1. (CmdPort) **Client -> Server** Hey I want to transfer file XXX with size YYYY
2. (CmdPort) **Server -> Client** Roger, connect to port 8217 and transfer the file
3. (8217) **Client -> Server** Connects, transfer the entire file, disconnect
4. (8217) **Server** Checks that the transferred size matches the one specified in step #1

That allows you to transfer several files at the same time. Let the server create a new listening socket using port 0. It tells the OS to select a free port. Then use `Socket.LocalEndpoint` to find out the port before sending it back in step #2.

The specified approach also lets you take advantage of `Socket.SendFile` which is probably the most effective and fastest way to send files using .NET.

*(FTP uses the same approach, as do bittorrent. You might have used a file manager when downloading files from the web. They takes a more extreme approach and splits up the file download over multiple sockets to get around web server bandwidth throttling.)*

**update in response to a comment:**

> my application also send folders , a folder may has 2000 files , many files size may equals to less than a kilo byte, it would be a huge mistake to connect for each file .. or maybe i should connect once for each task (a folder/ a file)

You did not specify that information in the original question, which made me assume that you only transfer one file at a time.

Batch transfers would work in the same way, just change so that step #1 sends a list of filename+size and then send all files after each other in step #3.

Comment: that's cool .. as i expected .. but in my code i let the dataServer active to accepts clients when a cmdPort is connected .. i mean i don't close it after the file received .. it closes when cmdPort disconnected.. i've already did a the filetransfer class that sends large files (>3 G.B) .. its great but tell more why Socket.SendFile is the fastest ? is about the packetsize it uses ?

Comment: That's what I'm saying. you should not keep the data transfer connections open. Data transfer connections should `Connect, send, disconnect`. Why do you keep the connection open? `Socket.SendFile` is the fastest since the .NET internals can solve the transfer in more effective way than you can in a higher layer (as a .NET user)

Comment: i read about it before i used my own code to send files ... but i couldn't get the amount of sent data and these options to show the progress (progressBar, timeleft,Speed .. etc)

Comment: That's true, you can't use a progress bar etc when using `SendFile`.

Comment: my application also send folders , a folder may has 2000 files , many files size may equals to less than a kilo byte, it would be a huge mistake to connect for each file .. or maybe i should connect once for each task (a folder/ a file)

Answer (score 0):

It would not be best practice to use 3 ports unless each operation was it's own application, i.e. a file server, an image server etc.  You should create one application listening on 1 port and then use Threading to accept multiple connections to the server (each with it's own instance of a StreamReader).  You could then write a parser method for the users input. For example, if the user sends the command "RECIEVE FILE", the server would expect a File, if the user sent the command "IMAGE" the server would expect an image.

An example of multi threaded servers can be found here:

http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-multi-threaded-server-socket.htm

Comment: That exactly what i did in my application .. but i need it to keep receiving commands in the same time when it expect the file .. like receiving a file while im exploring its files

Comment: Yes.  Did you have a look at that tutorial I sent you?  You could modify that to achieve this.

     clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient(); // Accepts the new connection
  
       handleClinet client = new handleClinet();  // client with it's own network stream.

You could then use the client objects Network Stream and process each command.

Comment: I've seen the tutorial .. the `handleClinet` is the same of my `Job` method .. and as you see every Socket accepted .. it passed for a new job thread.